# making migration by hand ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been learning rails, and am having an issue making a migration by hand. What I have done:

The filename is:

```
20150825194806_slug_unique_vacations.rb
```

which I made up. I tried cutting and pasting a migration and I named the class based on what I thought made sense:

```
class SlugUniqueIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :vacations, [:slug], :unique => true
  end
end
```

but I get this error:

```
cchilders@cody_pc:~/projects/rails_projects/vacation$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant SlugUniqueVacations
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is the correct way to migrate where you only want to make a single field that already exists in a table unique?

Comment: Class name should match filename. Name the class `SlugUniqueVacations`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migration file name and class name must be same.

```
class SlugUniqueVacations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :vacations, [:slug], :unique => true
  end
end
```

Comment: The only way Rails can guess which class to instantiate and invoke `change` on is by looking at the filename. Your filename needs to tell Rails the name of the class it contains, otherwise Rails cannot guess the name of the class to instantiate.